# Possible Bug: Completed 21 Review Tasks on Suggested Edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I don't know if this is a bug or intended functionality, but I'll list the steps I took to encounter this issue:

- Finish 20 (normal daily limit) review tasks on `suggested-edits`.
- Post a question/answer and have a low-rep user create an edit.
- Click the notification and choose `Improve Edit`.

Should I have been awarded an extra task for technically editing my own question? Also I know the actual limit is 40 reviews (given the number of tasks to be completed), but it seems odd that I would get an extra one here.

I realize this is a trivial question but I thought it was interesting and have never encountered such a thing before, so I figured I'd share what I found.

[Review Stats for Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After your 20 reviews, you did another review: the "Improve Edit" on the user's suggested edit. This counts as a review too, and you could still do this review because it was on your own post.

Because this was a review, there is no reason to not count it: the counter reflects the actual amount of reviews you did today.

Comment: Yes, I realize *how* it happened, but I'm not sure if it should have counted, considering I was already at the daily limit for that review queue.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: @TimLewis: reviews on your own posts are not subject to the review limit, because that'd lock out the author of the post (the most knowledgable person to review a suggested edit) from reviewing the edit. This is *by design*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, and I agree, but my question was should I have received credit for it? To me, it just seems odd that I would get that +1 task. Thanks for the comment-answer!

Comment: @TimLewis: I don't see why not; you got to the review before other reviewers got to it. Just because you cannot find more reviews in the review queue doesn't mean you should be prevented from reviewing further suggested edits on your own content, and if you are then reviewing, those should count.

Comment: @TimLewis: the limit isn't there to prevent you from somehow gaining more review counts against your account; it is there to ensure that no-one dominates the review queue, thereby setting the tone of the site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That makes sense. I didn't think about the limit that way, but I see the logic behind it. Thanks for clearing that up, will accept and close this answer/comments. Best of luck in the elections btw.