# Why can a user with 6 rep review suggested edits?

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was checking if there were more things to review and looking at who made reviews when I noticed something very odd. There was a user with 6 reputation who was in the list of suggested edits.

[image]

Can anyone explain or tell me what's going on or if this is just a bug?

Comment: Related: [21 suggested edit reviews completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290612/possible-bug-completed-21-review-tasks-on-suggested-edits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Can anyone explain or tell me what's going on

He was reviewing a suggested edit **to his own question**. Users are always able to accept or reject suggested edit to their own questions (or answers), regardless of their reputation.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I had no idea. But I don't have enough reputation myself to check it. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Just [take a look at the review-task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11078782), and you will be enlightened:

The user is marked as the posts author, and the author always can exercise a binding vote for suggested edits, even if he has exhausted his allotted tasks per day, or cannot ordinarily review at all due to insufficient reputation.

Comment: Perfect! I had no idea. But I don't have enough reputation myself to check it. Thanks a lot for the answer!